# How does a for loop within a .filter function for an array end?

Tags: javascript

The following is a program, is one that removes from the first argument, that is always an array, the elements equaling consecutive arguments. When I execute the following code, only the values equaling the first argument gets removed from the input array (first argument), but the rest are intact.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  var i;
  var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var arr_req = arr[0];
  arr_req = arr_req.filter(function(val) {
        for(i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(val === arr[i]) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
    return arr_req;
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

But when I use the following code inside the for loop, I get the correct expected output, that is `[1,1]`

```
arr_req = arr_req.filter(function(val) {
    for(i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(val === arr[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

So, why isn't the correct result obtained in the first case? Isn't it same as the latter? I am new to JavaScript. Can anyone explain?

Comment: In the first case, your `for` loop will only ever run once. The `return` statements in there break the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
function destroyer(arr) {
   var i;
   var arr=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
   var arr_req=arr[0];
   arr_req=arr_req.filter(function(val){
              var flag;
    for(i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
    {

        if(val===arr[i])
        {        
                flag=false;        
        return false;
        }else{
                flag=true;            
        }

    }
    return flag;
});
```

return arr_req;
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],2,3));